# Matching the second ip address in a range only when it's following a specific text

Tags: python, regex

I have the following patterns (each example is in a different file):

```
example one
-----------

alpha:    192.168.50.0 - 192.168.50.24
delta:    192.168.50.100 - 192.168.50.124
other fields: more stuff
....

example two
-------------

gamma: 200.0.0.0 - 200.0.0.64
lamda: 200.0.0.124 - 200.0.0.255
other  fields: more stuff
....
```

I'm using Python to iterate the files, and I'm trying to find a one liner to match only `'alpha'` or `'gamma'` occurrences, and only the second ip in the range. So in our examples it will be: `192.168.50.24` or `200.0.0.64`

Something like, that will give me only the second ip:

```
(?<=alpha:\s)|(?<=gamma:\s).*
```

Comment: While you can express any CIDR range in a regular expression, it may not necessarily be a very *nice* expression. If you're using Python there's [IP parsing and mask matching code already there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

Comment: I would love avoid using regex but how can I match only the section of IP that I need with the Python IP module? The text files have a lot of string lines and the order and form changes and isn't uniformes.

Comment: The issue is that the `.*` part only applies to the second alternation. I think you are better off using  a capture group due to the variable number of leading spaces https://regex101.com/r/A2BCva/1 Of course you can make the pattern more specific to match an ip like format.

Comment: Check for `text.startswith(('alpha', 'gamma')`, then `text.split('-')` and grab the second part. Or split on the `':`', grab the first part and check for alpha or gamma, then split on the `'-'` and grab the second half.

Comment: @The fourth bird Thanks you're a legend and a bee spelling champ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd always lean on the excellent [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library whenever dealing with IP addresses because of its easy validity checking (use a simpler regex and just try it), comparison methods (ip in network?), support for IPv4 and IPv6, and understanding of special ranges (global, link_local, multicast..) - additionally, you may consider a custom class for managing these ranges

If you eventually want the *complete* ranges and are working around it by just finding the second, something like this may more clearly get what you're after and be useful to build with
(note you can match `if instance.label:` in a script)

```py
class IPRange:

    def __init__(self, line=None, *, label=None, start=None, end=None):
        if line and (start or end):
             raise TypeError("only a line or start+end are expected")
        # adjust regex if IPv6 is needed
        # or I'd suggest `.split(":", 1)` and `.split(" - ")` again 
        if line:  # pull start and end from line
            match = re.match(r"^([^:]+):\s*([\d\.]{7,15})\s-\s([\d\.]{7,15})$", line)
            if not match:
                raise ValueError(f"not a valid line: {line}")
            _label, start, end = match.groups()
            label = label or _label  # allow setting label
        self.label    = label  # allow None
        # ValueError if either is not an IP Address
        self.ip_start = ipaddress.ip_address(start)
        self.ip_end   = ipaddress.ip_address(end)
        if self.ip_start > self.ip_end:  # NOTE allows ==
            raise ValueError(f"start must be before end: cmp({self.ip_start} > {self.ip_end})")
        # opportunity to reject special/reserved addresses or ranges

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.label}, {self.ip_start}, {self.ip_end})"

    def __contains__(self, other):
        """ support checking `ip in IPRange` """
        other = ipaddress.ip_address(other)
        # opportunity to reject special/reserved addresses or ranges
        return self.ip_start <= other <= self.ip_end
```

Example Usage

```py
>>> r = IPRange("alpha:    192.168.50.0 - 192.168.50.24")
>>> "192.168.50.1" in r
True
>>> "192.168.50.25" in r
False
>>> print(IPRange(label="foo", start="127.0.0.3", end="127.0.0.5"))
IPRange(foo, 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.5)
>>> print(IPRange(label="foo", start="127.0.0.3", end="127.0.0.2"))
[..]
ValueError: start must be before end: cmp(127.0.0.3 > 127.0.0.2)
```

Chewing on multiple lines

```py
for line in data.splitlines():
    try:
       print(IPRange(line))
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(f"failed: {repr(ex)}")
```

```
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: example one')
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: -----------')
failed: ValueError('None does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address')
IPRange(alpha, 192.168.50.0, 192.168.50.24)
IPRange(delta, 192.168.50.100, 192.168.50.124)
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: other fields: more stuff')
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: ....')
failed: ValueError('None does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address')
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: example two')
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: -------------')
failed: ValueError('None does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address')
IPRange(gamma, 200.0.0.0, 200.0.0.64)
IPRange(lamda, 200.0.0.124, 200.0.0.255)
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: other  fields: more stuff')
failed: ValueError('not a valid line: ....')
```

Also take a look at [`ipaddress.summarize_address_range(start, end)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.summarize_address_range) which might be a useful iterator (`__iter__` method?) too

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I appreciate the approach.

Answer (score 2):

In the pattern that you tried, the `.*` only applies to the second part of the alternation `|`

But if you would fix the issue with the alternation by grouping the lookarounds only, using `.*` would still match the rest of the line, and not only the second ip.

As there seem to be a varying number of leading spaces in the example data, you could consider using a capture group for the second ip, while matching the first ip and the spaces that precede it.

This is a shortened pattern to capture the part in the example data. If you want a better match for an ip like string, you can see [How to Find or Validate an IP Address](https://regular-expressions.info/ip.html).

```
\b(?:alpha|gamma):\s+\d[\d.]+\s+-\s+(\d[\d.]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:alpha|gamma):` Match either `alpha:` or `gamma:`
- `\s+\d[\d.]+` Match 1+ whitspace chars, a digit and 1+ digits or dots
- `\s+-\s+` Match a hyphen between 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d[\d.]+)` Capture **group 1**, match a digit followed by 1+ digits or dots

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c0iuCj/1)

Comment: Very well explained

Answer (score 1):

You could convert this into a dictionary without too much trouble and directly pinpoint anything you want. And even though this is 4 lines of actual string manipulation it's possibly still more efficient than regex.

```
data = """
alpha:    192.168.50.0 - 192.168.50.24
delta:    192.168.50.100 - 192.168.50.124
other fields: more stuff
"""

out = {}
for line in data.strip().split('\n'):
    if not line: continue

    k,v = line.split(':')        #get key:value pair
    v   = v.strip().split(' - ') #attempt a list

    #if len>1 keep it a list else grab only var
    out[k.strip()] = v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]


#PROOF
print(__import__('json').dumps(out, indent=4))
"""
{
    "alpha": [
        "192.168.50.0",
        "192.168.50.24"
    ],
    "delta": [
        "192.168.50.100",
        "192.168.50.124"
    ],
    "other fields": "more stuff"
}
"""
```

One bonus to doing it this way, is that you can cast values as you go (if that is something you needed). This way your `dict` not only has all the values, but they are all the proper type. I don't see anything in the example you posted that can benefit from this, but maybe you have a bunch of booleans, floats or ints in the `other_fields` part.

```
data = """
alpha:    192.168.50.0 - 192.168.50.24
delta:    192.168.50.100 - 192.168.50.124
other fields: more stuff
"""

import re

MTCFLOAT = re.compile(r'^-?\d*\.\d+$').match
MTCINT   = re.compile(r'^-?\d+$').match

#cast input to appropriate type
def cast(v:str|None):
    #None
    if v is None: return None
    
    #force to str and strip
    v = f'{v}'.strip()
    
    #bool
    if (vl := v.lower()) in ('true','false'):
        return vl == 'true'
        
    #str, int, float - typed as str if not a None, bool, int or float (ie. str by default)
    _i = bool(MTCINT(v))
    _f = bool(MTCFLOAT(v))
    v  = (str,int,float)[_f<<1|_i](v)
            
    return v

out = {}
for line in data.strip().split('\n'):
    if not line: continue
    k,v = line.split(':')
    v = [cast(_) for _ in v.split(' - ')]
    out[cast(k)] = v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]
```

Then you can take all that, slam it together, add in some dynamics, and end up with a little whack-a-mole parser that can handle all these off-formats that have separated key:value pairs

```
#utils.py

import re
from dataclasses import dataclass

MTCFLOAT = re.compile(r'^-?\d*\.\d+$').match
MTCINT   = re.compile(r'^-?\d+$').match


@dataclass
class Separators:
    pair  : str = ':'
    list  : str = ','
    entry : str = '\n'
    

class Data2Dict:
    def __init__(self, sep:Separators) -> None:
        self._sep = sep
            
    def cast(self, v:str|None) -> None|int|float|str|bool:
        if v is None: return None
        
        v = f'{v}'.strip()
        
        if (vl := v.lower()) in ('true','false'):
            return vl == 'true'
            
        _i = bool(MTCINT(v))
        _f = bool(MTCFLOAT(v))
        v  = (str,int,float)[_f<<1|_i](v)
                
        return v
        
    def parse(self, data:str, sep:Separators=None) -> dict:  
        sep = self._sep = (sep or self._sep) 
        
        out = {}
        for line in data.strip().split(sep.entry):
            if not line: continue

            k,v = line.split(sep.pair)
            v = [self.cast(_) for _ in v.split(sep.list)]

            out[self.cast(k)] = v if len(v) > 1 else v[0]   
        
        return out
```

---

```
from utils import *

data = """
alpha:    192.168.50.0 - 192.168.50.24
delta:    192.168.50.100 - 192.168.50.124
other fields: more stuff
"""

results = Data2Dict(Separators(list=' - ')).parse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from contextlib import ExitStack

pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+)(.*?-)(.*$)')
choices = (('alpha', "gamma"))
file_list = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt']

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(filename)) for filename in file_list]
    for f in files:
        for line in f:
            if line and line.split(":")[0] in choices:
                print(re.sub(pattern, r'\1 \3',line))
```

alpha  192.168.50.24

gamma  200.0.0.64